# Estimate shipping methods by address id Error REST API : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I am trying to call this magento 2 built in API :

```
  POST  http://domain.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id
```

In Body :

```
{"addressId": 194}
```

But I got this error:

```
{
    "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "addressId",
        "fieldValue": 194
    }
}
```

Can any body help ?

Answer (score 0):

The expected format for the body is slightly different:

```
{
  "address": {
    "id": 0,
    "region": "string",
    "region_id": 0,
    "region_code": "string",
    "country_id": "string",
    "street": [
      "string"
    ],
    "company": "string",
    "telephone": "string",
    "fax": "string",
    "postcode": "string",
    "city": "string",
    "firstname": "string",
    "lastname": "string",
    "middlename": "string",
    "prefix": "string",
    "suffix": "string",
    "vat_id": "string",
    "customer_id": 0,
    "email": "string",
    "same_as_billing": 0,
    "customer_address_id": 0,
    "save_in_address_book": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
      "gift_registry_id": 0
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "string",
        "value": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So in your case I would try:

```
{
  "address": {
    "id": 194
  }
}
```